# How to use input to TextInput in kivy to get different output

Tags: python, kivy

I wrote the following code.

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from functools import partial
Config.set('graphics', 'width', 300)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 300)

from kivy.lang import Builder
Builder.load_string("""
<KeybindTestWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'

        TextInput:
            id: textinput1
            size_hint_y: 0.45
            text: ""
            on_focus: root.set_activeTextInput("textinput1")

        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: 0.1

        TextInput:
            id: textinput2
            size_hint_y: 0.45
            text: ""
            on_focus: root.set_activeTextInput("textinput2")
""")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

class KeybindTestWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(KeybindTestWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.bufHotKeyTextinputName = ""

        #key bind
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(
            self._keyboard_closed, self, 'text')
        if self._keyboard.widget:
            pass
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self._on_keyboard_up)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        pass

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        self.ids[self.bufHotKeyTextinputName].text = keycode[1]
        return True

    def _on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
        return True

    def set_activeTextInput(self, textInputName, *args):
        self.bufHotKeyTextinputName = textInputName

class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return KeybindTestWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

In the above code, if I type from the keyboard when TextInput is in focus, the text will change in response to the key input.

For example, if I press the space key on my keyboard, TextInput will show "spacebar".

However, there is one problem with the above code.

That's what happens when I press "a" on the keyboard, as in the image below, and TextInput shows "aa".

[image]

The _on_keyboard_down function is executed a little before the keyboard input, so it duplicates the input.

I've tried the TextInput option readonly, which makes the on_key_down unresponsive.

Is there any good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, is to use the `Clock` to schedule the call *after* the `TextInput` has finished drawing its letter (which we will erase).
You will also need `from functools import partial`

```py
    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.clear_and_set, keycode))
        return True

    def clear_and_set(self, keycode, *args):
        self.ids[self.bufHotKeyTextinputName].text = keycode[1]
```